# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in HealthKit in reading dateOfBirthWithError

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

When I call the following function to read dataOfBirth, I keep receiving bad access error while testing on device. I'm using Swift 2.0 in Xcode 7 beta

```
    func updateUsersAge(){

    do{
        var error : NSError!
        let birthdate = try currentHealthStore.dateOfBirthWithError()

        let now = NSDate()

        let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.NSYearCalendarUnit, fromDate: birthdate, toDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)
        let age = dateComponents.year

        self.ageValueLabel.text = NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(NSNumber(integer: age), numberStyle: NSNumberFormatterStyle.NoStyle)

    }
    catch{

        print("Not avaialble")
    }
}
```

currentHealthStore is defined in AppDelegate as global variable:

```
let currentHealthStore = HKHealthStore()
```

And the error is received once this line is executed:

```
let birthdate = try currentHealthStore.dateOfBirthWithError()
```

Comment: Have you stepped into the code for dateOfBirthWithError() in the debugger?

Comment: Yes and nothing is shown in debugger, I receive this error once it starts to execute this line

Comment: Post the code for dateOfBirthWithError?

Comment: Its a native method in HealthKitStore, check this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/dateOfBirthWithError:

Comment: Have you verified that currentHealthStore is still a valid object by the time that line is reached?

Comment: Yes its valid and have checked that

Comment: Is this with iOS 8 on the phone or iOS 9?

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me in swift 2, XCode 7.1.1

```
let birthDay = try healthStore.dateOfBirth()
```

The name dateOfBirthWithError has been used before the error was passed back with a throws.